# Checking format errors in a String using Java

Tags: java, regex, string, dice

So this is a part of a dice rolling program I have been plugging away at for the past few days... Language parsing isn't my strong suit, so I thought I would ask for some help.

The input buttons are `[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]`, `[3]`, `[4]`, `[5]`, `[6]`, `[7]`, `[8]`, `[9]`, `[0]`, `[d4]`, `[d6]`, `[d8]`, `[d10]`, `[d12]`, `[d20]`, and `[ROLL]`; `[ROLL]` uses a separate handler from the others. `codeStr` is a String and `etCalc` is a EditText.

The cases I need to handle especially are in my TODO tags, namely when extra numbers come after the [dn] button press currently it will roll a larger number die instead of disallowing the action from being performed which was my intent. And `[dn][dn]`, where two die rolls come after each other implying dice multiplication which my program isn't set to handle.

```
public void calcButtonClick(View view) {
    Button b = (Button) view;
    String buttonText = b.getText().toString();

    // TODO: Case: dn[extraneous numbers]
    // TODO: Case: d[n]d[n]
    codeStr = codeStr + buttonText;
    etCalc.setText(codeStr);
}
```

Comment: Please be more clear about what you're actually asking for.

Comment: I need to handle the two cases so I can throw some kind of error without giving a strange result or crashing the program.